# How to modify datePicker style swiftui 2?

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, swift5, ios14

I have a calendar made with datePicker in swiftui 2, I am looking to customize this calendar I have already seen .datePickerStyle() and all these styles but it doesn't correspond to my expectations, I'm trying to reproduce that (below)

[image: what i search]

My current code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExercisePageView: View {
    @State var date = Date()
    var dateFormat = DateFormat()
    var dateStyle = GraphicalDatePickerStyle()
    var closedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let currentDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: Date())!
        let fiveDaysLater = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 5, to: Date())!
        
        return currentDate...fiveDaysLater
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack{
                
                Text("\(dateFormat.dateToString("dd / MMMM", date))")
                DatePicker("date picker test", selection: $date, in: closedRange , displayedComponents: .date)
                    
                    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                    .clipped()
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .accentColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result of my code
[image]

Comment: You would have to make it from scratch (from buttons and labels etc). The built in `DatePicker` is not customisable to that degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thank you for those who read this post we can not modify as it was said by Sweeper, you have to create your own component